# Apache/PHP file type confusion

Tags: php, apache

I have a quick question about changing the file types PHP parses. [This](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/17/1/2) website gave this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But I'm not clear what file this goes into. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about this - what I need is Apache to parse PHP files that have a mp4 extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line goes into a file called `.htaccess`, that changes the Apache server configuration for the folder it is on, and all its subfolders (Unless otherwise specified)

Your server should parse php files with the *.php* file extension by default though. You could use that to add custom file formats for example.

To parse .mp4 files, like you said in the comments, add to your .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .mp4
```

Comment: So can I just make a .htaccess file in any folder that will contain the files with the custom extension? Or does it have to be in a specific Apache folder?

Comment: You could place that in any folder you want, although if you want it for the whole server you would simply place it in your root directory.

Comment: OK, thanks. I needed Apache to parse MP4 files that contain PHP.

Comment: You could just write `AddType application/x-httpd-php .mp4`, and your server will parse mp4 files through the PHP interpreter. Placing that in an .htaccess in the mp4 folder will set this only for that folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to write that in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

That makes Apache parse `.php` files through the PHP interpreter.

You can either add that to your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file, depending on what you have access to.